# Why am I infinitely looping through my for() loops?

Tags: javascript, json

Would someone please review this code and tell me why the for loops are going infinite? I need a fresh set of eyes. Thank you!

```
var routeData = [{"id":1,"c1_id":43,"c2_id":56,"cost":20,"c1_x":658,"c1_y":68,"c2_x":568,"c2_y":149,"owned":false},{"id":2,"c1_id":27,"c2_id":56,"cost":25,"c1_x":571,"c1_y":10,"c2_x":568,"c2_y":149,"owned":false},{"id":3,"c1_id":39,"c2_id":56,"cost":20,"c1_x":510,"c1_y":53,"c2_x":568,"c2_y":149,"owned":false},{"id":4,"c1_id":56,"c2_id":8,"cost":18,"c1_x":568,"c1_y":149,"c2_x":495,"c2_y":202,"owned":false},{"id":5,"c1_id":56,"c2_id":49,"cost":14,"c1_x":568,"c1_y":149,"c2_x":605,"c2_y":217,"owned":false},{"id":6,"c1_id":49,"c2_id":4,"cost":14,"c1_x":605,"c1_y":217,"c2_x":572,"c2_y":282,"owned":false},{"id":7,"c1_id":8,"c2_id":10,"cost":11,"c1_x":495,"c1_y":202,"c2_x":448,"c2_y":250,"owned":false},{"id":8,"c1_id":4,"c2_id":48,"cost":10,"c1_x":572,"c1_y":282,"c2_x":504,"c2_y":293,"owned":false},{"id":9,"c1_id":48,"c2_id":10,"cost":12,"c1_x":504,"c1_y":293,"c2_x":448,"c2_y":250,"owned":false},{"id":10,"c1_id":10,"c2_id":31,"cost":17,"c1_x":448,"c1_y":250,"c2_x":450,"c2_y":370,"owned":false},{"id":11,"c1_id":48,"c2_id":33,"cost":16,"c1_x":504,"c1_y":293,"c2_x":530,"c2_y":373,"owned":false},{"id":12,"c1_id":10,"c2_id":35,"cost":14,"c1_x":448,"c1_y":250,"c2_x":372,"c2_y":250,"owned":false},{"id":13,"c1_id":33,"c2_id":47,"cost":17,"c1_x":530,"c1_y":373,"c2_x":479,"c2_y":431,"owned":false},{"id":14,"c1_id":33,"c2_id":31,"cost":15,"c1_x":530,"c1_y":373,"c2_x":450,"c2_y":370,"owned":false},{"id":15,"c1_id":47,"c2_id":57,"cost":9,"c1_x":479,"c1_y":431,"c2_x":479,"c2_y":466,"owned":false},{"id":16,"c1_id":57,"c2_id":60,"cost":12,"c1_x":479,"c1_y":466,"c2_x":484,"c2_y":527,"owned":false},{"id":17,"c1_id":60,"c2_id":17,"cost":12,"c1_x":484,"c1_y":527,"c2_x":521,"c2_y":511,"owned":false},{"id":18,"c1_id":17,"c2_id":58,"cost":13,"c1_x":521,"c1_y":511,"c2_x":598,"c2_y":527,"owned":false},{"id":19,"c1_id":58,"c2_id":36,"cost":10,"c1_x":598,"c1_y":527,"c2_x":650,"c2_y":584,"owned":false},{"id":20,"c1_id":57,"c2_id":7,"cost":16,"c1_x":479,"c1_y":466,"c2_x":430,"c2_y":432,"owned":false},{"id":21,"c1_id":57,"c2_id":54,"cost":14,"c1_x":479,"c1_y":466,"c2_x":430,"c2_y":462,"owned":false},{"id":22,"c1_id":31,"c2_id":59,"cost":16,"c1_x":450,"c1_y":370,"c2_x":350,"c2_y":344,"owned":false},{"id":23,"c1_id":35,"c2_id":59,"cost":14,"c1_x":372,"c1_y":250,"c2_x":350,"c2_y":344,"owned":false},{"id":24,"c1_id":59,"c2_id":29,"cost":19,"c1_x":350,"c1_y":344,"c2_x":260,"c2_y":314,"owned":false},{"id":25,"c1_id":59,"c2_id":12,"cost":12,"c1_x":350,"c1_y":344,"c2_x":299,"c2_y":395,"owned":false},{"id":26,"c1_id":12,"c2_id":2,"cost":6,"c1_x":299,"c1_y":395,"c2_x":290,"c2_y":400,"owned":false},{"id":27,"c1_id":2,"c2_id":22,"cost":10,"c1_x":290,"c1_y":400,"c2_x":255,"c2_y":412,"owned":false},{"id":28,"c1_id":22,"c2_id":29,"cost":16,"c1_x":255,"c1_y":412,"c2_x":260,"c2_y":314,"owned":false},{"id":29,"c1_id":29,"c2_id":14,"cost":14,"c1_x":260,"c1_y":314,"c2_x":232,"c2_y":257,"owned":false},{"id":30,"c1_id":29,"c2_id":9,"cost":10,"c1_x":260,"c1_y":314,"c2_x":209,"c2_y":300,"owned":false},{"id":31,"c1_id":9,"c2_id":32,"cost":8,"c1_x":209,"c1_y":300,"c2_x":192,"c2_y":308,"owned":false},{"id":32,"c1_id":32,"c2_id":16,"cost":12,"c1_x":192,"c1_y":308,"c2_x":170,"c2_y":225,"owned":false},{"id":33,"c1_id":16,"c2_id":15,"cost":10,"c1_x":170,"c1_y":225,"c2_x":195,"c2_y":166,"owned":false},{"id":34,"c1_id":32,"c2_id":37,"cost":11,"c1_x":192,"c1_y":308,"c2_x":155,"c2_y":315,"owned":true},{"id":35,"c1_id":37,"c2_id":19,"cost":9,"c1_x":155,"c1_y":315,"c2_x":101,"c2_y":285,"owned":false},{"id":36,"c1_id":19,"c2_id":1,"cost":12,"c1_x":101,"c1_y":285,"c2_x":70,"c2_y":330,"owned":false},{"id":37,"c1_id":19,"c2_id":5,"cost":12,"c1_x":101,"c1_y":285,"c2_x":131,"c2_y":243,"owned":false},{"id":38,"c1_id":22,"c2_id":41,"cost":12,"c1_x":255,"c1_y":412,"c2_x":304,"c2_y":461,"owned":true},{"id":39,"c1_id":41,"c2_id":18,"cost":12,"c1_x":304,"c1_y":461,"c2_x":350,"c2_y":499,"owned":true},{"id":40,"c1_id":18,"c2_id":45,"cost":8,"c1_x":350,"c1_y":499,"c2_x":370,"c2_y":504,"owned":false},{"id":41,"c1_id":45,"c2_id":54,"cost":13,"c1_x":370,"c1_y":504,"c2_x":430,"c2_y":462,"owned":false},{"id":42,"c1_id":54,"c2_id":34,"cost":14,"c1_x":430,"c1_y":462,"c2_x":400,"c2_y":532,"owned":false},{"id":43,"c1_id":34,"c2_id":51,"cost":19,"c1_x":400,"c1_y":532,"c2_x":408,"c2_y":623,"owned":false},{"id":44,"c1_id":41,"c2_id":26,"cost":16,"c1_x":304,"c1_y":461,"c2_x":300,"c2_y":554,"owned":true},{"id":45,"c1_id":26,"c2_id":55,"cost":11,"c1_x":300,"c1_y":554,"c2_x":270,"c2_y":573,"owned":false},{"id":46,"c1_id":26,"c2_id":40,"cost":12,"c1_x":300,"c1_y":554,"c2_x":350,"c2_y":585,"owned":false},{"id":47,"c1_id":40,"c2_id":51,"cost":13,"c1_x":350,"c1_y":585,"c2_x":408,"c2_y":623,"owned":false},{"id":48,"c1_id":60,"c2_id":53,"cost":17,"c1_x":484,"c1_y":527,"c2_x":470,"c2_y":610,"owned":false},{"id":49,"c1_id":53,"c2_id":51,"cost":11,"c1_x":470,"c1_y":610,"c2_x":408,"c2_y":623,"owned":false},{"id":50,"c1_id":53,"c2_id":42,"cost":13,"c1_x":470,"c1_y":610,"c2_x":540,"c2_y":659,"owned":false},{"id":51,"c1_id":42,"c2_id":6,"cost":10,"c1_x":540,"c1_y":659,"c2_x":510,"c2_y":705,"owned":false},{"id":52,"c1_id":6,"c2_id":53,"cost":16,"c1_x":510,"c1_y":705,"c2_x":470,"c2_y":610,"owned":true},{"id":53,"c1_id":6,"c2_id":13,"cost":13,"c1_x":510,"c1_y":705,"c2_x":433,"c2_y":673,"owned":false},{"id":54,"c1_id":53,"c2_id":13,"cost":15,"c1_x":470,"c1_y":610,"c2_x":433,"c2_y":673,"owned":false},{"id":55,"c1_id":13,"c2_id":51,"cost":15,"c1_x":433,"c1_y":673,"c2_x":408,"c2_y":623,"owned":false},{"id":56,"c1_id":51,"c2_id":25,"cost":16,"c1_x":408,"c1_y":623,"c2_x":338,"c2_y":693,"owned":false},{"id":57,"c1_id":25,"c2_id":28,"cost":11,"c1_x":338,"c1_y":693,"c2_x":298,"c2_y":675,"owned":false},{"id":58,"c1_id":28,"c2_id":50,"cost":8,"c1_x":298,"c1_y":675,"c2_x":282,"c2_y":710,"owned":false},{"id":59,"c1_id":50,"c2_id":23,"cost":12,"c1_x":282,"c1_y":710,"c2_x":210,"c2_y":699,"owned":false},{"id":60,"c1_id":40,"c2_id":52,"cost":11,"c1_x":350,"c1_y":585,"c2_x":314,"c2_y":639,"owned":false},{"id":61,"c1_id":52,"c2_id":28,"cost":10,"c1_x":314,"c1_y":639,"c2_x":298,"c2_y":675,"owned":false},{"id":62,"c1_id":41,"c2_id":11,"cost":12,"c1_x":304,"c1_y":461,"c2_x":232,"c2_y":490,"owned":true},{"id":63,"c1_id":11,"c2_id":21,"cost":9,"c1_x":232,"c1_y":490,"c2_x":230,"c2_y":513,"owned":true},{"id":64,"c1_id":55,"c2_id":21,"cost":15,"c1_x":270,"c1_y":573,"c2_x":230,"c2_y":513,"owned":true},{"id":65,"c1_id":55,"c2_id":46,"cost":9,"c1_x":270,"c1_y":573,"c2_x":240,"c2_y":596,"owned":false},{"id":66,"c1_id":46,"c2_id":24,"cost":19,"c1_x":240,"c1_y":596,"c2_x":170,"c2_y":560,"owned":false},{"id":67,"c1_id":21,"c2_id":3,"cost":11,"c1_x":230,"c1_y":513,"c2_x":150,"c2_y":528,"owned":true},{"id":68,"c1_id":3,"c2_id":24,"cost":13,"c1_x":150,"c1_y":528,"c2_x":170,"c2_y":560,"owned":false},{"id":69,"c1_id":24,"c2_id":20,"cost":12,"c1_x":170,"c1_y":560,"c2_x":112,"c2_y":567,"owned":false},{"id":70,"c1_id":20,"c2_id":38,"cost":12,"c1_x":112,"c1_y":567,"c2_x":38,"c2_y":553,"owned":true},{"id":71,"c1_id":24,"c2_id":44,"cost":22,"c1_x":170,"c1_y":560,"c2_x":61,"c2_y":661,"owned":false},{"id":72,"c1_id":38,"c2_id":44,"cost":16,"c1_x":38,"c1_y":553,"c2_x":61,"c2_y":661,"owned":true},{"id":73,"c1_id":59,"c2_id":30,"cost":16,"c1_x":350,"c1_y":344,"c2_x":340,"c2_y":425,"owned":false},{"id":74,"c1_id":30,"c2_id":41,"cost":12,"c1_x":340,"c1_y":425,"c2_x":304,"c2_y":461,"owned":false},{"id":75,"c1_id":30,"c2_id":18,"cost":12,"c1_x":340,"c1_y":425,"c2_x":350,"c2_y":499,"owned":true}];
var trainData = [{"id":2,"type":"STANDARD","game_player_id":2,"game_id":1,"route_id":18,"origin_city_id":58,"dest_city_id":17,"track_unit":3,"direction":"_","line":"RED","status":"ENROUTE","goods":[{"train_id":2,"goods_id":31,"name":"Furniture"},{"train_id":2,"goods_id":7,"name":"Chocolate"}]},{"id":3,"type":"STANDARD","game_player_id":3,"game_id":1,"route_id":30,"origin_city_id":9,"dest_city_id":29,"track_unit":2,"direction":"_","line":"RED","status":"ENROUTE","goods":[{"train_id":3,"goods_id":19,"name":"Marble"}]},{"id":4,"type":"STANDARD","game_player_id":4,"game_id":1,"route_id":5,"origin_city_id":49,"dest_city_id":56,"track_unit":2,"direction":"_","line":"RED","status":"ENROUTE","goods":[]},{"id":5,"type":"STANDARD","game_player_id":5,"game_id":1,"route_id":1,"origin_city_id":56,"dest_city_id":43,"track_unit":0,"direction":"_","line":"RED","status":"ARRIVED","goods":[]},{"id":15,"type":"STANDARD","game_player_id":1,"game_id":1,"route_id":67,"origin_city_id":21,"dest_city_id":3,"track_unit":8,"direction":"+","line":"RED","status":"ARRIVED","goods":[{"train_id":15,"goods_id":29,"name":"Timber"}]}];
var routeCount = [routeData.length];
var train = [];
var trackColor = "#888";
for(var i = 0; i < routeData.length; i++) {
  var trainCount = 0;
  train = [];
  routeCount[i] = [];
  routeCount[i]["route_id"] = routeData[i]["id"];
  trackColor = routeData[i]["owned"] ? "#555" : "#888";
  for(var j = 0; j < trainData.length; j++) {
    if(trainData[j]["route_id"] == i) {
new Dialog().showMessage("test", j+":route match on "+i);
      train[trainCount] = trainData[j];
      trainCount++;
    }
  }
if(train[0]) { new Dialog().showMessage("train", i+":train="+train.toSource()); }
drawTrack(parseInt(routeData[i]["c1_y"]),
                                                 parseInt(routeData[i]["c1_x"]),
                                                 parseInt(routeData[i]["c2_y"]),
                                                 parseInt(routeData[i]["c2_x"]),
                                                 trackColor,
                                                 train);
}
```

Comment: Try stepping through it in a script debugger, like Firebug.

Comment: Did you ever find your answer, Chris?

Comment: No, no solution yet.

Here's some more info: the Dialog on line 14 shows the same thing infinitely:

3:route match on 1

It's as if i and j are not being incremented at all.

Comment: Matt, yes, a debugger would be very helpful. I have Firebug and I tried setting a breakpoint in my code and refreshing the page, but the browser did not break at the breakpoint.

Comment: Did you ever find your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

runs fine for me if I comment out the call to drawTrack

Comment: Good point! When I commented out drawTrack, it ran fine for me as well. It seems my problem is somewhere in drawTrack. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the problem actually starts in this code. When I call 'train[trainCount] = trainData[j];' it is not copying trainData[j].goods which is an array nested in trainData. I think this is breaking drawTrack. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get js to copy all nested levels of the array? Thanks.

Comment: You should either edit your question to update it with this new question, or ask a new question with a link to this one. The former method is preferable.

Answer (score 5):

[JSLint](http://JSLint.com) found the following problems:

> ```
> Error:  
>
> Problem at line 10 character 17: ['route_id'] is better written in dot
> notation.
>
> routeCount[i]["route_id"] = routeData[i]["id"];
>
> Problem at line 10 character 44: ['id'] is better written in dot
> notation.
>
> routeCount[i]["route_id"] = routeData[i]["id"];
>
> Problem at line 11 character 29: ['owned'] is better written in dot
> notation.
>
> trackColor = routeData[i]["owned"] ? "#555" : "#888";
>
> Problem at line 13 character 21: ['route_id'] is better written in dot
> notation.
>
> if(trainData[j]["route_id"] == i) {
>
> Problem at line 14 character 1: 'new' should not be used as a
> statement.
>
> new Dialog().showMessage("test", j+":route match on "+i);
>
> Problem at line 19 character 16: 'new' should not be used as a
> statement.
>
> if(train[0]) { new Dialog().showMessage("train",
> i+":train="+train.toSource()...
>
> Problem at line 20 character 33: ['c1_y'] is better written in dot
> notation.
>
> drawTrack(parseInt(routeData[i]["c1_y"]),
>
> Problem at line 20 character 11: Missing radix parameter.
>
> drawTrack(parseInt(routeData[i]["c1_y"]),
>
> Problem at line 21 character 72: ['c1_x'] is better written in dot
> notation.
>
> parseInt(routeData[i]["c1_x"]),
>
> Problem at line 21 character 50: Missing radix parameter.
>
> parseInt(routeData[i]["c1_x"]),
>
> Problem at line 22 character 72: ['c2_y'] is better written in dot
> notation.
>
> parseInt(routeData[i]["c2_y"]),
>
> Problem at line 22 character 50: Missing radix parameter.
>
> parseInt(routeData[i]["c2_y"]),
>
> Problem at line 23 character 72: ['c2_x'] is better written in dot
> notation.
>
> parseInt(routeData[i]["c2_x"]),
>
> Problem at line 23 character 50: Missing radix parameter.
>
> parseInt(routeData[i]["c2_x"]),
>
> Implied global: Dialog 14,19, drawTrack 20
> ```

Comment: JSLint huh? Looks like a lifesaver.

Comment: Yea; I should probably switch those to <pre> tags.

Comment: Tried to add <pre> tags, looked fine in preview but really got botched on submission.

Comment: Yeah... but how do you know half of these errors weren't caused by SO's worthless Javascript-powered syntax highlighter?  That thing has messed up my snippets so many times.

Comment: @Josh Stodola : I'm sure the world would love you if you could write a better one for us? Until there's a better one, this is what the SO team has got.

Comment: @Josh Stodola — Funny, I've usually found the JS syntax highlighting to be more reasonable in edge cases than the server-side markdown engine its emulating.

Answer (score 1):

My fresh set of eyes see two `for` loops, which you say are running infinitely.

```
for(var i = 0; i < routeData.length; i++)

for(var j = 0; j < trainData.length; j++)
```

Let's assume the first loop is infinite. If that's the case `i < routeData.length` is always true. I can only think of two ways that would be possible.

- `i` is decremented somewhere in the body of the loop, so that its value doesn't increase to reach `routeData.length`. But I don't see that happening, and I think that would be easy to spot.
- `routeData.length` is increasing, so that `i` never catches up. It's possible that the `drawTrack` function could be adding elements to `routeData`, increasing its length.

The problem could also be in the second loop (or both); the same reasoning applies.

I think ultimately you're going to find a problem in the `drawTrack` function. Either it's appending to one of the arrays or it contains its own infinite loop.

Comment: Patrick, you are correct. My problem was in drawTrack. Thanks for the help.